# probability counting order with no replacement

Tags: probability

The code to a bank vault consists of 4 characters fixedly chosen among the 26 letters of the English alphabet and the numbers 1-9.

At least 2 of the 4 characters must be letters.

Determine the number of possible codes that do not include any repetition of numbers or letters in the code.

Here is what i computed
Since its asking for at least 2 of the 4 characters then LLNN+LLLN+LLLL is what I'm looking for. Looking for where L denoted letter and N denoted number.since there is no repetition then LLNN=26*25*9*8=46800 and LLLN=26*25*24*9=140,400 and LLLL=26*25*24*23=358800.SO LLNN+LLLN+LLLL=546000.But this is not one of the available solution.

Comment: evertime I compute I get  546,000 as my answer

Comment: Side note: Improve the question a little bit. Show what you've tried (that comment above for example), and explain why you think it's wrong. You might get some good answers if you do that. You'll probably get your question closed otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Self-explanatory answer:

$$\binom{26}{2}\cdot\binom{26-2+9}{2}=171600$$